# Issues in applying styleClass to inputText placed on column of datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**CSS:**

```
.sample {
   background: red;
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<p:inputText id="inputTxtOnForm" value="hi" styleClass="sample"/>

<p:column id="articleDescription" headerText="Article Description"
               filterBy="#{article.description}" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
               <p:inputText id="inputTxtOnDataTable" value="#{article.description}"
                  styleClass="sample" />
 </p:column>
```

`inputTxtOnForm` is placed on a form directly. `inputTxtOnDataTable` is placed on a column of a datatable.

The `styleClass` on the `inputText` having `id="inputTxtOnForm"` is getting applied. But, `styleClass` is not getting applied on the `inputText` having `id="inputTxtOnDataTable"`. The properties of primefaces' `themes.css` are not getting over-ridden in the latter case.

Is it a known bug ? Is there any workaround for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sample {
   background: red  !important;
}
```

worked for me. Probably, the background is marked as important in primefaces' css.