# JSF style invalid input

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to change an input style when it is not valid , in advance to it's message.
I found [this](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/styling-invalid-input-fields-with-jsf/) example, and tried it, but could not see the invalid input background color changing. when the input is invalid, I see it's inavlid message and I can see that it's styleClass has been changed to the one in the postValidationLisenter.

Is there a reason that i see the correct styleClass but the input style is not changed? is there another way to change the input's style, but not from the client side? I want it to be automatic for every invalid input.

***UPDATE***:
I tried now to add the styleClass to the input in the input itself, but still could not view the border and background color. if i put theses style defenitions inside `style` in the input , I'm able to see them. Is it some kind of bug? I know that it can't be the css file beacuse i have there other css defenitions which are shown.

Comment: It's possible that other styles are overriding your definitions. Use Firebug or the inspection tool of your browser to see what styles are actually being applied to your element. Try using `style` directly instead of `styleClass`, to see if will work. If it works, it's a case of overrided styles.

Comment: Your question tag says richfaces but the example you link to is from primefaces. They are different libraries, how can you be sure that the example applies to your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was that the css definition had a missing `!important` in it, and this is why i couldn't see the border color. so it's not even related to the invalid issue.
I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589858/issues-in-applying-styleclass-to-inputtext-placed-on-column-of-datatable).